# implement request/response port forwarding between two Linux machine

Tags: linux, webserver, portforwarding

I have a web server(A) running on private network and I have another host machine(B) within same private network.

example: 
Web Server A:
  private ip: 10.128.0.2
  Application running on port: 8088
Host machine B:
  Private ip: 10.128.0.5
  public ip: 54.34.23.56

The client send the request the host machine B https://54.34.23.56:8088. The host machine B transfer the request to Web Server 10.128.0.2:8088. And the client get back the response from application running on web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nginx proxy_pass to solve your problem.